# Finding X and Y to solve var(X) and var (Y) in probability

Tags: probability

Suppose you toss a coin four times.

The sample space

```
Ω = {HHHH, HHHT, HHT H, . . . , T T T T }
```

contains 16 outcomes and you should assume each outcome is equally likely.

Let $X$ be the *Binomial random*
variable that corresponds to the number of heads in an outcome,

*e.g., X(HT HT) = 2.*

Let $Y$ be the *Bernoulli
random variable* that evaluates to 1 if there is an even number of heads in the outcome,

*e.g., Y (HHHT) = 0
and Y (HT HT) = 1.*

What is the value of E(X), E(Y) and var(X), var(Y)?

I got that:$$E(X) = np$$

$$E(Y) = p$$

$$ therefore, E(X) = (4)(\frac {1}{2})$$
$$E(Y) = \frac 12$$

Assuming these are correct

I believe that Var's formula is: $$E[(X - E[X])^2]$$

What would be X and Y in this case? I'm confused...

Comment: Check your notes or your textbook. What's the definition of var?

Comment: The definition of $X$ didn't say anything about even or odd numbers. Any outcome from 0 to 4 is possible. The definition of $Y$ has only outcomes $0$ or $1$. For $\mathrm{var}(X)$ you use $X$, for $\mathrm{var}(Y)$ you use $Y$.